# MongoDB : Multi Update with where condition

Tags: mongodb

Requirement: Get All documents where point < 90 and increment 'point' by +20
Data:

```
 { "_id" : 1, "student" : 1, "type" : "exam", "point" : 115 }
    { "_id" : 2, "student" : 2, "type" : "exam", "point" : 85 }
    { "_id" : 3, "student" : 3, "type" : "exam", "point" : 115 }

Query tried : 
// query below
```

db.points.update({},{$inc:{point:20},point:{lt:110}},{multi:true})

```
On executing : fn[0] == '$'is seen and query has not affected any changes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query as follows :

```
db.points.update({point:{$lt:110}},{$inc:{point:20}},false,true)
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of the boolean values false and true.

Comment: Third parameter is used for upsert (insert if not exists) and last parameter is for multiple update. You can read details in this document : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 0):

There is no where condition in your update

db.points.update({ point : { $lt: 90 }  },{ $inc: { point:20 } },{multi:true})

point : { $lt: 90 } selects only documents where a value in point is lower then 90 and increases by 20

Comment: Works ... I missed out encapsulating the second condition within a {} or basically a document.Do we have a better editor than the basic mongo console?